# Kendo Grid calculate difference between two row values

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to get the row item values of the first and second row and calculate a difference und display it as an custom aggregate. This should happen after every sort so it should check if there are only two rows showing. So for example if the turnover for the year 2017 is 10000€ and 5000€ for 2018 the result should be -50% .

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({                              
            toolbar: ["excel"],
            excel: {
                fileName: "turnover.xlsx",
                allPages: true
            },  
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: "data/turnovers.php",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },                  
                schema: {
                    data: "data",                       
                    total: function(result) { 
                    var data = this.data(result);
                    return data ? data.length : 0;
                    },                      
                    model: {
                                fields: {
                                    January: { type: "number" },
                                    February: { type: "number" },
                                    March: { type: "number" },
                                    April: { type: "number" },
                                    May: { type: "number" },
                                    June: { type: "number" },
                                    July: { type: "number" },
                                    August: { type: "number" },
                                    September: { type: "number" },
                                    October: { type: "number" },
                                    November: { type: "number" },
                                    December: { type: "number" },
                                    sum: { type: "number" },
                                    jahr: { type: "string" }                                        
                                }
                    }

                },
                pageSize: 50,
                aggregate: [ { field: "January", aggregate: "sum" },
                             { field: "February", aggregate: "sum" },
                             { field: "March", aggregate: "sum" },
                             { field: "April", aggregate: "sum" },
                             { field: "May", aggregate: "sum" },
                             { field: "June", aggregate: "sum" },
                             { field: "July", aggregate: "sum" },
                             { field: "August", aggregate: "sum" },
                             { field: "September", aggregate: "sum" },
                             { field: "October", aggregate: "sum" },
                             { field: "November", aggregate: "sum" },
                             { field: "December", aggregate: "sum" },
                             { field: "sum", aggregate: "sum" }

                             ]
            },
             height: 870,                
             scrollable: true,
             sortable: true,
             filterable: true,
             pageable: {
                        refresh: true,
                        pageSizes: true
                    },
            columns: [
                        {
                            field: "January",
                            title: "January",
                            filterable: false,
                            format: "{0:c2}",
                            footerTemplate: "sum: #: kendo.toString(sum, '\\#\\#,\\# €') #"
                        },
                        {
                            field: "February",
                            title: "February",
                            filterable: false,
                            format: "{0:c2}",
                            footerTemplate: "sum: #: kendo.toString(sum, '\\#\\#,\\# €') #"

                        },
                        {
                            field: "March",
                            title: "March",
                            filterable: false,
                            format: "{0:c2}",
                            footerTemplate: "sum: #: kendo.toString(sum, '\\#\\#,\\# €') #"

                        },
                        {
                            field: "April",
                            title: "April",
                            filterable: false,
                            format: "{0:c2}",
                            footerTemplate: "sum: #: kendo.toString(sum, '\\#\\#,\\# €') #"
                        },
                        {
                            field: "May",
                            title: "May",
                            filterable: false,
                            format: "{0:c2}",
                            footerTemplate: "sum: #: kendo.toString(sum, '\\#\\#,\\# €') #"

                        },
                        {
                            field: "June",
                            title: "June",
                            filterable: false,
                            format: "{0:c2}",
                            footerTemplate: "sum: #: kendo.toString(sum, '\\#\\#,\\# €') #"

                        },
                        {
                            field: "July",
                            title: "July",
                            filterable: false,
                            format: "{0:c2}",
                            footerTemplate: "sum: #: kendo.toString(sum, '\\#\\#,\\# €') #"
                        },
                        {
                            field: "August",
                            title: "August",
                            filterable: false,
                            format: "{0:c2}",
                            footerTemplate: "sum: #: kendo.toString(sum, '\\#\\#,\\# €') #"

                        },
                        {
                            field: "September",
                            title: "September",
                            filterable: false,
                            format: "{0:c2}",
                            footerTemplate: "sum: #: kendo.toString(sum, '\\#\\#,\\# €') #"

                        },
                        {
                            field: "October",
                            title: "October",
                            filterable: false,
                            format: "{0:c2}",
                            footerTemplate: "sum: #: kendo.toString(sum, '\\#\\#,\\# €') #"
                        },
                        {
                            field: "November",
                            title: "November",
                            filterable: false,
                            format: "{0:c2}",
                            footerTemplate: "sum: #: kendo.toString(sum, '\\#\\#,\\# €') #"

                        },
                        {
                            field: "December",
                            title: "December",
                            filterable: false,
                            format: "{0:c2}",
                            footerTemplate: "sum: #: kendo.toString(sum, '\\#\\#,\\# €') #"

                        },
                        {
                            field: "sum",
                            title: "sum",
                            format: "{0:c2}",
                            filterable: false,
                            footerTemplate: "sum: #: kendo.toString(sum, '\\#\\#,\\# €') #"
                        }
                   ]
        });
    });
```

approach:

```
function calculatediff(){

            var entityGrid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");       
            var data = entityGrid.dataSource.data();
            var totalNumber = data.length;

            if(totalNumber = 2) {
                var currentDataItem = data[0];
                var currentDataItem = data[1];
                row1 = currentDataItem.January;
                row2 = currentDataItem.January;
                diff = ((row1-row2)/((row1+row2)/2))*100
            }               
        }
```

Comment: I see two options: first, compute the value once the data has been read but here the question is that you can receive the data out of order so you need to implement it carefully; second, compute it as kendo displays but this is tricky because you should play with HTML content. I would go with the first. Can you guarantee that data is received in order? Can you guarantee it in the implementation of `data/turnovers.php`?

Comment: it should always take the first and second row so it doesnt really matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data source supported [aggregate](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-aggregate) functions are only *average, count, max, min, sum* and does not have an framework for adding custom functions that work in the same manner.

The aggregates that are computed become available to the `footerTemplate` as a `data` object that is available at template resolution time.  Thus, the footer can contain a function that is passed this object and perform the custom computation.

This [dojo snippet](http://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/Egucu) demonstrates the technique.

The dataSource was tweaked to be two rows, and both count and sum (supported aggregate functions) aggregation is specified for each column.

```
          data: [
          { January: 20, February: 30, March: 140, sum: 190 },
          { January: 30, February: 20, March: 50, sum: 100 }
          ],
          pageSize: 50,
          aggregate: [ { field: "January", aggregate: "count" },  { field: "January", aggregate: "sum" },
                       { field: "February", aggregate: "count" }, { field: "February", aggregate: "sum" },
                       { field: "March", aggregate: "count" },    { field: "March", aggregate: "sum" },
                       { field: "sum", aggregate: "count" },      { field: "sum", aggregate: "sum" },
                     ]
          },
```

In the columns declaration all the footer templates were tweaked to invoke a custom function that is passed the aggregate data object and the field.

```
{
    field: "January",
    /* ... */
    footerTemplate: "#= customFooter(data,'January') #"
},
{
    field: "February",
    /* ... */
    footerTemplate: "#= customFooter(data,'February') #"

},
{
    field: "March",
    /* ... */
    footerTemplate: "#= customFooter(data,'March') #"

},
{
    field: "sum",
    /* ... */
    footerTemplate: "#= customFooter(data,'sum') #"
}
```

Code running inside the footerTemplates does not know the field, so you have to repeat the field name inside the template.

Finally, customFooter() function uses the field aggregates 1) to determine if the special result should be computed and 2) as a partial contribution to the computation.  The difference is computed directly from the data source.

```
function customFooter (ds_agg, field) {
  if (ds_agg[field].count == 2) {
    var ds = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    var diff = ds.view()[0][field] - ds.view()[1][field];
    var ratio = ( diff / ( ds_agg[field].sum / 2 ) ) * 100;

return "diff: " + diff + "<br />sum: " + ds_agg[field].sum + "<br /> ratio: " + ratio;
  }      
}
```

[image]